# Multivariable chain rule confusion (Jacobian matrix).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm given the functions:

$$g: \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3:g=(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))\quad \text{and } f:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R.$$

And I'm asked to find the jacobian matrix of $h=f \circ g$, would that be:

$$
Dh=(f_u\ f_v \ f_w) \text { or } \ Dh=(f_x\ f_y\ f_z)?
$$

I have another exercise which asks the same thing and gives the functions $g(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z), f(u,v)=(u^2-v^2,u-v)$, and thus, I don't know how to solve it.

Could anyone explain which one is the jacobian and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem (Chain Rule) :** Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be open, $g : U \to V, f : V \to \mathbb{R}^l$ be two functions, $a \in U$ and $b := g(a) \in V$. If $g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is differentiable at $b$, then $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(f \circ g)'(a) = f'(b) g'(a)$.

In the first case of your question, therefore, since
$$
f'=\begin{pmatrix}f_x&f_y&f_z\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
g'=\begin{pmatrix}u_x&u_y&u_z\\v_x&v_y&v_z\\w_x&w_y&w_z\end{pmatrix},
$$
we find
\begin{align}
h'(p)&=\begin{pmatrix}f_x(b)&f_y(b)&f_z(b)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_x(p)&u_y(p)&u_z(p)\\v_x(p)&v_y(p)&v_z(p)\\w_x(p)&w_y(p)&w_z(p)\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}f_x(b)u_x(p)+f_y(b)v_x(p)+f_z(b)w_x(p)\\f_x(b)u_y(p)+f_y(b)v_y(p)+f_z(b)w_y(p)\\f_x(b)u_z(p)+f_y(b)v_z(p)+f_z(b)w_z(p)\end{pmatrix}^T
\end{align}
where $p:=(x,y,z)$ and $b:=(u(p),v(p),w(p))$.

Comment: And what would $b$ be? $g(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Yes, $b=g(p)=g(x,y,z)=(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))=(u(p),v(p),w(p))$.

Comment: Thanks for the explicitness, I was having trouble with this!